# Can I ask how to find someone else to do home improvement for me?

Tags: discussion, scope

On Home Improvement, would it be on-topic to ask for a website recommendation where I would seek to purchase somebody elses time to do DIY-related work for me?  For example, would the following question be on-topic on Home Improvement?

> **Looking for a web application that brings handymen etc. and their customers together**
>
> I'm looking for a web application where customers can review the work of handymen, painters, cleaners, plumbers, electricians, carpenters, etc.: anyone performing manual labour for others for a fee. On the web platform I envision, the handyman (etc.) advertises their services, and customers can review and rate their work. Perhaps it also includes a service where customers can post a request and handymen can bid to carry this out. What Tripadvisor and Kayak are for hotels, what Urbanspoon is for restaurants, and what Yelp is for businesses in general.
>
> I am aware of [werkspot](https://www.werkspot.nl), but this is only for The Netherlands. My existing approach is to look at craigslist/kijiji/gumtree or whatever the localised equivalent is, but searching for a particular service will yield many results with no way of systematically estimating previous customer satisfaction.
>
> Can anyone recommend a web application according to my description?

Would this be on-topic?

Comment: I was going to ask this on [Website recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations/), but the proposal was closed.  And on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), [website recommendations are off-topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites/219).

Answer (score 5):

This sort of question should be off topic.

Recommendation questions are **hard** and it's no surprise that most sites don't allow them. Those that do have *very* strict rules about what makes a good question.

There are a number of problems with this type of question:

1. They attract spam.
2. They go out of date very quickly.
3. Did I mention they attract spam?
4. Answers are often just a link with no explanation of how that meets the questions requirements.

You can always ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement).

Comment: All of those reasons, plus they attract a lot of spam too.